# (More) Rigorous Proof of the Formula for the Angle Between Two Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I looked into half a dozen proofs for the angle between vectors formula involving cosine.

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec w}{\|\vec v\|\|\vec w\|}$$

They all start like this:

An $n$-dimensional triangle is constructed and projected onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ somehow (<-- somehow!):

[image]

How this projection happens is not really important though, because adding $\vec v$ and $\vec w - \vec v$ lands you at $\vec w$, which demonstrates that these vectors form 'a closed path'... lacking proper terminology here.

Then some major hand waving happens, in which the vectors are replaced by their magnitudes and it is stated that thus the law of consines can be applied to this triangle, because the vectors have ben replaced by their lengths.

[image]

But... that is not rigorous. Or I at least it makes it not explicit why this step is valid, i.e. for instance what the property is called that is proved to hold in this case.

I mean, who says that just because the $n$-D vectors can be arranged to form a closed path (demonstrably), that we can just willy nilly assume that we can apply the law of consines to a triangle constructed from the magnitudes of the vectors?

Can you provide me with the reason why this step is allowed and ideally a proof as well?

Examples for proofs that do this magic step (Yes, I don't like reading):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbBGgHDhmVg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adOtjgAeIbE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AWob_z74Ks

Comment: What is your definition of an angle?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean, if you were to prove a theorem about angles, you better have a precise definition of an object that your theorem is about. So, how do you define an angle in a triangle? Some people take the formula using the dot product as the definition.

Comment: But I provided the formula to be proven, which involves the dot product. Is there a difference to what you are referring to?

Comment: One cannot prove anything about objects which are undefined. Voting to close.

Comment: Reduce to the $2$-dimensional case via rotation, then prove it with a direct computation.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Still don't know what you have in mind. You mentioned the definition involving the dot product. I am asking about a step in the proof that shows the angle between vectors in n dimensions can be computed the same way as in 2 dimensions, involving the dot product. Instead of "Voting for close" you could rather help me understand what exactly you are talking about. (I'd assume that is what you are on this site for, helping others understand stuff?)

Comment: @user3578468 He is trying to help. You seem to have an operation $O: \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^n  \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ which takes two vectors and assigns a real number, which you call "angle". He is asking what is the definition of this operation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you define the scalar product $x\cdot y$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$  by
$$x\cdot y=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\, y_k\ ,$$
whereby $(x_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ are the coordinates of $x$ with respect to the standard basis. This basis  is **orthonormal**. It is a standard fact that formula $(1)$ is valid with respect to  **any** orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ of the vector space ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Now to angles between vectors. The *angle* $\theta$ between two nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$ is defined to be the shorter of the two arcs on the unit circle connecting the tips of the unit vectors $u/|u|$ and $v/|v|$. It is stated that this angle $\theta$ between two vectors $u$, $v\in{\mathbb R}^n$ is characterized by $$\cos\theta={u\cdot v\over |u|\>|v|}\ .$$
We therefore have to prove the claim that
$$\cos\theta=u\cdot v\qquad\bigl(|u|=|v|=1\bigr)\ .$$
To this end choose an orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ with $e_1:=u$ and $v\in\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$. Then all coordinates  $u_k$ and $v_k$ with $k>2$ are zero, and we have $$u\cdot v=1\>v_1+0\>v_2=v_1=\cos\theta\ ,$$ because the cosine of the angle $\theta$ enclosed by $u$ and $v$ is **by definition** the first coordinate  of $v$ when $u=e_1$ and $v$ is another point of $S^1$ in the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane.